# Why won't the "Configure Continuous Delivery" option appear?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to set up continuous deployment in Visual Studio 2017 and got stuck on step one. I installed the *[Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/02/06/continuous-delivery-tools-extension-visual-studio-2017/)*. It appears under the *Installed* list in *Extensions and Updates*, and it has a *Disable* button next to it, so I assume it is enabled. From everything I've read, there's supposed to be an option labeled "Configure Continuous Delivery" when I right-click the project. Nothing new appears for me. I've tried restarting Visual Studio and rebooting my computer.

I thought that maybe it wasn't supported because it wasn't a .NET Core application, or because I'm using TFS and not VSTS. So I created a new .NET Core web application and pushed it to VSTS, and still do not have any new menu options on the project. For both projects, the repo is Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Visual Studio do you use? The extension [Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEDevOpsMSFT.ContinuousDeliveryToolsforVisualStudio) only supports Visual Studio 2017 for now.

I tested the extension with VS 2017 (`Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.4.4`). Then option "`Configure Continuous Delivery to Azure`" displayed there as expected.

Please note that, you need to right click on the **Solution** but not the project.

Reference this article : [TFVC support and other enhancements hit Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/11/27/tfvc-support-and-other-enhancements-hit-continuous-delivery-tools-for-visual-studio/)

[image]

Comment: You were right about clicking right-clicking the solution instead. I feel a bit foolish for not trying that first, but thank you. The handful of tutorials I was following must have been wrong. They also showed the option as not including "to Azure." Did those things change recently with an update? Also, I think I misunderstood this tool. It seems to be for configuring CI/CD specifically for VSTS and Azure, which I was able to get working, but I found I could just enable CI/CD from within the TFS web app (Build & Release tab) with my own build and release definitions.